# iCheck on() method callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback, icheck

I'm using a bootstrap template which use [iCheck v1.0.2](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck)

When I create an input like this :

```
<input id="follow_us" type="checkbox">
```

It generate the result :

```
<div class="icheckbox_minimal-grey" style="position: relative;">
  <input id="follow_us" type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins>
</div>
```

I want to detect the change on this checkbox. [As the documentation says](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/#callbacks), there is a method for that :

```
$('#follow_us').on('ifChanged', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

But this did absolutely nothing. Same for every other callbacks. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't [initialize](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/#initialize) the checkbox as an iCheck object. 
To do so, you will need to add something along the lines of:

```
$('#follow_us').iCheck();
```

to your script before the iCheck callback will work. Check the documentation (linked above) for more info on options you can set at initialization.